# Issue with extra nils in quicksort result

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, quicksort

I'm new to lisp, and am writing code for quicksort. I am almost done, although the output is giving me some trouble. This is currently what I have:

```lisp
(defun fil(P L)
    (if (null L) nil
        (if (funcall P (first L)) (cons (first L) (fil P (rest L)))
            (fil P (rest L)))))

(defun qs(L)
    (if (null L) nil
        (let ((x (first L))
            (gt (fil (lambda (x) (<= (first L) x))(rest L) ))
            (lt (fil (lambda (x) (> (first L) x))(rest L)))) 
             (cons (cons (qs lt) (first L)) (qs gt)))))
             
(write (qs '(4 2 3 1 7 3 5 3 6)))
```

This works, but the output looks like this:

```lisp
((((((NIL . 1)) . 2) (NIL . 3) (NIL . 3) (NIL . 3)) . 4)
 (((NIL . 5) (NIL . 6)) . 7))
```

I am not sure where the extra nils and periods and parentheses are coming from or how to fix it. Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Look at

```
(cons '(a b c d) 'e)
```

Above code does not append `E` to the list.

```
CL-USER 4 > (cons '(a b c d) 'e)
((A B C D) . E)
```

It creates a new cons cell (a two element container) with the first arg and the second arg with its elements.

What you need, is to APPEND lists into a result list.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to what @RainerJoswig said:

```
(defun %filter (pred l)
  (cond ((null l) nil)
        ((funcall pred (car l)) (cons (car l) (%filter pred (cdr l))))
        (t (%filter pred (cdr l)))))

(defun quicksort (l)
  (cond ((null l) nil)
        (t (let ((greater-than (%filter (lambda (x) (<= (car l) x)) (cdr l)))
                 (less-than (%filter (lambda (x) (> (car l) x)) (cdr l))))
             (append (quicksort less-than) (list (car l)) (quicksort greater-than))))))

(quicksort '(4 2 3 1 7 3 5 3 6))
;; (1 2 3 3 3 4 5 6 7)
```

Alternatively also:

```
(defun %filter (pred l)
  (mapcan (lambda (x) (if (funcall pred x) (list x) nil)) l))

(defun quicksort (l)
  (cond ((null l) nil)
        (t (append (quicksort (%filter (lambda (x) (< x (car l))) (cdr l)))
                   (list (car l))
                   (quicksort (%filter (lambda (x) (<= (car l) x)) (cdr l)))))))
```